# Netty library not work in android release apk?

Tags: android, netty

I made proxy server with netty on android by using the codes available on netty GitHub example, actually, I just copy them and use them in android.
here is the netty proxy server example :
https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/4.0/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/proxy
Now I faced two problems, the first netty does not work properly in the first run but after closing the app and open it again it works well I don't know why in the first run it doesn't work.
2. netty does not work in the release mode and when I check the logs I see this error

```
Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<g.b.b.k>: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: 
        at void g.b.b.m.<clinit>() (ByteBufUtil.java:82)
        at void g.b.b.k.<clinit>() (ByteBufAllocator.java:24)
        at void g.b.c.f0.<init>(g.b.c.e, g.b.c.y0) (DefaultChannelConfig.java:59)
        at void g.b.c.f0.<init>(g.b.c.e) (DefaultChannelConfig.java:72)
        at void g.b.c.i1.e.<init>(g.b.c.i1.g, java.net.ServerSocket) (DefaultServerSocketChannelConfig.java:50)
        at void g.b.c.i1.k.b$b.<init>(g.b.c.i1.k.b, g.b.c.i1.k.b, java.net.ServerSocket) (NioServerSocketChannel.java:201)
        at void g.b.c.i1.k.b$b.<init>(g.b.c.i1.k.b, g.b.c.i1.k.b, java.net.ServerSocket, g.b.c.i1.k.b$a) (NioServerSocketChannel.java:199)
        at void g.b.c.i1.k.b.<init>(java.nio.channels.ServerSocketChannel) (NioServerSocketChannel.java:90)
        at void g.b.c.i1.k.b.<init>() (NioServerSocketChannel.java:75)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:-2)
        at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:343)
        at g.b.c.e g.b.c.z0.a() (ReflectiveChannelFactory.java:44)
        at g.b.c.j g.b.a.a.v() (AbstractBootstrap.java:310)
        at g.b.c.j g.b.a.a.o(java.net.SocketAddress) (AbstractBootstrap.java:272)
        at g.b.c.j g.b.a.a.g(java.net.SocketAddress) (AbstractBootstrap.java:268)
        at g.b.c.j g.b.a.a.e(int) (AbstractBootstrap.java:246)
        at void d.a.a.f.d.run() (MainProxyServer.java:55)
        at void d.a.a.j.j$c$a.a(m.a.a.a) (Main.kt:115)
        at java.lang.Object d.a.a.j.j$c$a.invoke(java.lang.Object) (Main.kt:94)
        at void m.a.a.b$a.a() (Async.kt:138)
        at java.lang.Object m.a.a.b$a.invoke() (Async.kt:-1)
        at java.lang.Object m.a.a.c.call() (Async.kt:-1)
        at void java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run() (FutureTask.java:266)
        at void java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run() (ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
        at void java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at void java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at void java.lang.Thread.run() (Thread.java:919)
```

but it works in debug mode well.

Comment: I am doing same work like you, I found this code (https://github.com/monkeyWie/proxyee) ,and I modified some codes so it can run on android, there is not error happen, but other device can not reach this proxy server. Can you give me some idea to figure it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

about the first problem maybe you need to add ProviderInstaller into your app because some android versions like android 5 seems can not handle SSL but by adding this I think the problem will be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

About the second problem, there are 2 options to resolve it:

1. just add `-keep class io.netty.**{*;}`
   to the file named `proguard-rules.pro` under this module.
2. disable code confuse, modify file named `build.gradle` under this module like this:

```
.....
buildTypes {
....
      release {
          minifyEnabled false
          .....
      }
....
}
....
```

**Pick one** in your condition.

Comment: Please add any further questions in the comments or as a new question.

Comment: @Yatin what? why you can edit my answer? i want this authority too ... i just said it because maybe he can give me some ideas in the communication. btw, i  feel disrespected because you edit my content at will.

Comment: Hello, my intentions weren't to disrespect you. Answers aren't for further clarifications. You can ask those questions in the comments. I have restored your answer to its original form.

Comment: @Yatin Actually don't need to roll it all back. Your grammar and format are better. I am a reasonable person can accept criticism. It would be enough to put my question back if it is ok.

Comment: And I aware now, I will ask questions in the comment next time.